# How to deal with moment dates in a loop?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs

I am having a hard time, figuring this one out. I want to get the difference on both dates based on the specified period.

I have below the snippet. Whenever I click the button, it should populate the array with the difference (based on specified period).

But, what is currently happening, is once I clicked the button, it populated the same dates. Any ideas?

```js
var fooObj = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.month = ko.observable();
    self.formatted = ko.computed(function() {
        return month().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY');
    });
};

var vm = (function() {
    var startDate = ko.observable(moment([2015, 10, 1])),
        startDateFormat = ko.computed(function() {
            return startDate().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY');
        }),
  endDate = ko.observable(startDate().add(5, 'days')),
        endDateFormat = ko.computed(function() {
            return endDate().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY');
        }),
        dateDiff = endDate().diff(startDate(), 'days'),
        foo = ko.observableArray(),
        test = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i<=5; i++){
                foo.push(startDate().add(1, 'days'));
            }
        };
    
    return {
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        foo: foo,
        test: test,
        dateDiff: dateDiff,
        startDateFormat: startDateFormat,
        endDateFormat: endDateFormat
    };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre><br />
<button data-bind="click: $root.test">Click me for test</button>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'd call a well minimised question, however I can suggest to you that in my own use of moment, this works fine: `var beg = moment(Date1, Format); var end = moment(Date2, Format); var diff_seconds = end.diff(beg);`

Comment: @Michael do you have any idea why I am getting the same dates once I clicked the button? anyway, i'll try your suggestion

Comment: Not really, not without getting your code working myself and debugging.

Comment: @Michael I wonder what's wrong. Is it something to do with mutating moment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are getting caught in a subtle syntax trap that is an easy-to-make mistake.  `moment.js` provides method chaining syntax which provides the source of the confusion in your case.

As an example, when you are setting the default value for your `endDate` this way, based on `startDate`:

`endDate = ko.observable(startDate().add(5, 'days'))`

you are not getting the result you expect because method chaining gives you the original value and then adds 5 days to it.

Instead, if you clone the `moment` object and then add you will get the result I believe you are expecting:

`endDate = ko.observable(moment(startDate()).add(5, 'days'))`

and you will also need to do the same inside the loop in your `test` method:

`foo.push(moment(startDate()).add(i, 'days'));  // use index var i for number of days`

The complete runnable example is here:

```js
var vm = (function() {
    var startDate = ko.observable(moment([2015, 10, 1])),
        startDateFormat = ko.computed(function() {
            return startDate().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY');
        }),
        // make sure to clone startDate before add
 endDate = ko.observable(moment(startDate()).add(5, 'days')),
        endDateFormat = ko.computed(function() {
            return endDate().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY');
        }),
        dateDiff = endDate().diff(startDate(), 'days'),
        foo = ko.observableArray(),
        test = function(){
            for(var i = 0; i<=5; i++){
                // make sure to clone startDate before adding days
                foo.push(moment(startDate()).add(i, 'days'));  // use index var i for number of days
            }
        };
    
    return {
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        foo: foo,
        test: test,
        dateDiff: dateDiff,
        startDateFormat: startDateFormat,
        endDateFormat: endDateFormat
    };
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre><br />
<button data-bind="click: $root.test">Click me for test</button>
```

Comment: I see. So it has something  to do with cloning the dates. So if I don't use cloning, it mutates the original value as well?